# Removal of everything Ruby and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can completely remove everything Rails and Ruby? I thought I removed everything but when I type ruby -v it stills displays a version of ruby (1.9.3p0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you installed Ruby and Rails. If you are on Windows, just go to Control Panel, Programs and Features, and uninstall Ruby and the Rails Installer. If on other systems, like Linux, maybe "aptitude purge ruby".

Comment: Thank you! the aptitude worked! I typed in ton of commands but not all of them FULLY erased everything

Comment: So you have both installed Ruby with aptitude and rvm, this is not recommended. Please consider : http://rvm.io/rvm/best-practices

Answer (score 1):

If using RVM, the easiest way to remove all traces of it from your system is to run `rvm implode` from the command line.

You should probably also edit your `~/.bashrc` file to remove the added references to RVM as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check how you had installed rvm - system wide or per user . What you can do is , type in 'rvm implode' . Manually remove all the rvm folders from root . Also any edit you made in your bashrc or bash_profile must be removed .